# Why my below javascript code in asp.net not working?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function validate() {
    summary += isvalidFirstName();
    summary += isvalidMobile();
    summary += checkPassword();
    summary += checkEmail();
    if (summary != "") {
        alert(summary);
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
}

function isvalidFirstName() {
    var uid;
    var temp = document.getElementById("<%=txtFirstName.ClientID %>");
    uid = temp.value;
    if (uid == "") {
        return ("Please enter firstname" + "\n");
    } else
        return "";
}

function isvalidMobile() {
    var mob = /^[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$/;
    var txtMob = document.getElementById(txtMobile);
    if (mob.test(txtMob.value) == false) {
        alert("Please enter valid mobile number");
        txtMob.focus();
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
}

function checkPassword(inputtxt) {
    var pass = /^[A-Za-z]\w{7,14}$/;
    if (inputtxt.value.match(pass)) {
        alert("Password is correct");
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Wrong...!");
        return false;
    }
}

function checkEmail(inputtxt) {
    var mail = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    if (inputtxt.value.match(mail)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Please enetr a valid email id");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

I have added the above javascript code inside an .ASPX page and called the function validate on button click but it is not working. Can anyone help me?

Comment: any error in console ?

Comment: This seems a bit scattered. `var txtMobile` is undefined in the snippet. checkPassword and checkEmail both take parameters but aren't passed any. Can you restructure the code into a StackOverflow code snippet? Just replace the handful of ASP tags with constants and some sample, unstyled html.

Comment: There is no error in console, only validation is not working.